# setting the ng-model value with ng-repeat and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple array like so:

```
$scope.otherItems = [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E"
        ];
```

and I wish to loop through this array and assign the values to checkboxes like so:

```
<label ng-repeat="o in otherItems"> {{ o }}
 <input ng-model="myform.otherItems" type="checkbox" value="{{ o }}">
</label>
```

Now the problem I have here is that when I check on any item they are all checked! This is due to the ng-model. All of my checkboxes have the same value for the `ng-model`. I would like to collect the individual checkboxes when submitting / set the `ng-model`  like so: myform.otherItems.valueOfo, so I get an object of the selected checkboxes. However when I try and set the `ng-model` like so `ng-model="myform.otherItems.o"` or `ng-model="myform.otherItems[o]"` I get errors. How do I best accomplish what I want? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `myForm.otherItems` different from `$scope.otherItems`? Or is it the same array?

Comment: myForm.otherItems is what I wish to collect/submit as I pass the myForm object that contains other items like textboxes, etc, when I submit the form, $scope.otherItems is the array to populate/loop through the checkboxes and isn't submitted, does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You want to identify it by the index of the array element.

```
ng-model="myform.otherItems[{{$index}}]"
```

Can't try it at the moment but this might work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can perhaps change the format of otherItems, or assign the values to a new array, then you can assign a `selected` variable to each item in the list and use otherItems as the model. You can then watch for changes on the model and update the myform object.

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YQ2qJ/1/

**View:**

```
<div ng-app=myApp>
    <div ng-controller=myController>
        <label ng-repeat="o in otherItems">{{ o.name }}
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="o.selected" value="{{ o.name }}">
        </label>
        <p>{{myform}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.otherItems = [
        {name: "A",
         selected: false
        },
        {name: "B",
         selected: false
        },
        {name: "C",
         selected: false
        },
        {name: "D",
         selected: false
        },
        {name: "E",
         selected: false
        }
    ];
    $scope.myform = {};
    $scope.$watch("otherItems", function() {
        $scope.myform.otherItems = $scope.otherItems;
    });
}]);
```